# Mapping through two data sets with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Suppose I have two key-value data sets--Data Sets A and B, let's call them.  I want to update all the data in Set A with data from Set B where the two match on keys.

Because I'm dealing with such large quantities of data, I'm using Hadoop to MapReduce.  My concern is that to do this key matching between A and B, I need to load all of Set A (a lot of data) into the memory of every mapper instance.  That seems rather inefficient.

Would there be a recommended way to do this that doesn't require repeating the work of loading in A every time?

Some pseudcode to clarify what I'm currently doing:

```
Load in Data Set A # This seems like the expensive step to always be doing
Foreach key/value in Data Set B:
   If key is in Data Set A:
      Update Data Seta A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the MapReduce framework includes [the following steps](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/mapred_tutorial.html#Payload):

1. Map
2. Sort/Partition
3. Combine (optional)
4. Reduce

You've described one way to perform your join: loading all of Set A into memory in each Mapper. You're correct that this is inefficient.

Instead, observe that a large join can be partitioned into arbitrarily many smaller joins if both sets are sorted and partitioned by key. MapReduce sorts the output of each Mapper by key in step (2) above. Sorted Map output is then partitioned by key, so that one partition is created per Reducer. For each unique key, the Reducer will receive all values from both Set A and Set B.

To finish your join, the Reducer needs only to output the key and either the updated value from Set B, if it exists; otherwise, output the key and the original value from Set A. To distinguish between values from Set A and Set B, try setting a flag on the output value from the Mapper.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying the Hadoop `-input` should be -both- sets A and B (with a flag to distinguish them from each other in the values), and then in the reduction step they'll be grouped together so it'll be possible to join them.  Is that correct?

Comment: Right, you'd input both A and B to your mappers and ensure that you're outputting a flag so that the reducers can distinguish between the two. I'm also assuming you're writing your own `Map` (implementing `mapred.Mapper`) and `Reduce` (implementing `mapred.Reducer`) classes. Like @joe-k says in a separate answer, Pig, Hive, and Cascading are all legitimate solutions that will generate this code for you and run on Hadoop.

Comment: You can do a small optimisation using Bloom Filter, which will work nice if Set A is a lot bigger than Set B and there are records which do not match to Set B and Set B does not fit into memory. Create a MapReduce Job which trains a Bloom Filter on Set B, than in the final MapReduce Job do all that was suggested, but in the Mapper filter Set A using Bloom Filter, that will reduce the amount of spilled records from Set A that do not have matching Set B records, thus your job might run a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers posted so far are correct - this should be a Reduce-side join... but there's no need to reinvent the wheel! Have you considered [Pig](http://pig.apache.org), [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/), or [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) for this? They all have joins built-in, and are fairly well optimized.

Comment: Wow, pretty cool.  For now I'm going to stick with Hadoop but I may learn one of these frameworks down the road

Answer (score 2):

[This video tutorial](http://www.cloudera.com/resource/mapreduce_algorithms/) by Cloudera gives a great description of how to do a large-scale Join through MapReduce, starting around the 12 minute mark.
Here are the basic steps he lays out for joining records from file B onto records from file A on key K, with pseudocode. If anything here isn't clear, I'd suggest watching the video as he does a much better job explaining it than I can.

In your Mapper:

```
K from file A:
  tag K to identify as Primary Key
  emit <K, value of K>

K from file B:
  tag K to identify as Foreign Key
  emit <K, record>
```

Write a Sorter and Grouper which will ignore the PK/FK tagging, so that your records are sent to the same Reducer regardless of whether they are a PK record or a FK record and are grouped together.

Write a Comparator which will compare the PK and FK keys and send the PK first.

The result of this step will be that all records with the same key will be sent to the same Reducer and be in the same set of values to be reduced. The record tagged with PK will be first, followed by all records from B which need to be joined. Now, the Reducer:

```
value_of_PK = values[0] // First value is the value of your primary key
for value in values[1:]:
  value.replace(FK,value_of_PK) // Replace the foreign key with the key's value
  emit <key, value>
```

The result of this will be file B, with all occurrences of K replaced by the value of K in file A. You can also extend this to effect a full inner join, or to write out both files in their entirety for direct database storage, but those are pretty trivial modifications once you get this working.

Comment: Nice.  Wouldn't it work to tag the values hash in A and B rather than the key itself?  Then I wouldn't need to write my own Sorter and Grouper, and I could just loop through the group in the Reduce step to see if they were both there

Comment: @babonk Sorry, not sure what you mean. You mean tag the values during the hashing phase?

Comment: You seemed to suggest tagging K, rather than value of K.  I was just saying it might be easier to just tag the value so I dont need to write my own sorter/grouper

Comment: @babonk you could do it that way, but then you'd have no way of ensuring the PK comes first, meaning you would have to loop through your list of values twice. Sorting the PK first drops the time complexity from O(2n) to O(n), which isn't as big a deal if you have a small dataset, but when you're working in terabytes it can make a huge difference.