# Filtering AVRO Data from 2 datasets

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

**Use-case:**

I had 2 dataset/fileset Machine (Parent) and Alerts (Child). 
Their data is also stored in two avro files viz machine.avro and alert.avro.

Alert schema had machineId : column type int.

How can I filter data from machine if there is a dependency on alert too? (one-to-many).

e.g. get all machines where alert time is between 2 time-stamp.

Any e.g. with source will be great help...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Got answer in another thread....

[Mapping through two data sets with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397378/mapping-through-two-data-sets-with-hadoop)

Posting comments from that thread...

According to the documentation, the MapReduce framework includes the following steps:

```
Map
Sort/Partition
Combine (optional)
Reduce
```

You've described one way to perform your join: loading all of Set A into memory in each Mapper. You're correct that this is inefficient.

Instead, observe that a large join can be partitioned into arbitrarily many smaller joins if both sets are sorted and partitioned by key. MapReduce sorts the output of each Mapper by key in step (2) above. Sorted Map output is then partitioned by key, so that one partition is created per Reducer. For each unique key, the Reducer will receive all values from both Set A and Set B.

To finish your join, the Reducer needs only to output the key and either the updated value from Set B, if it exists; otherwise, output the key and the original value from Set A. To distinguish between values from Set A and Set B, try setting a flag on the output value from the Mapper.